# Pivot string column in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am new to pandas and I have below data

```
      Country    Skills
0   India   Finance
1      UK       Law
2      US  Computer
```

I am trying to convert this to

```
   India UK US Skills
0   Y    N  N  Finance
1   N    Y  N  Law
2   N    N  Y  Computer
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

```py
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> df = pd.read_clipboard()
>>> df
  Country    Skills
0   India   Finance
1      UK       Law
2      US  Computer

>>> dummies = pd.get_dummies(df['Country'])
>>> dummies
   India  UK  US
0      1   0   0
1      0   1   0
2      0   0   1

>>> result = pd.concat([dummies, df], axis=1)
>>> result
   India  UK  US Country    Skills
0      1   0   0   India   Finance
1      0   1   0      UK       Law
2      0   0   1      US  Computer

>>> result = result.drop('Country', axis=1)
>>> result
   India  UK  US    Skills
0      1   0   0   Finance
1      0   1   0       Law
2      0   0   1  Computer

>>> result = result.replace({1:'Y', 0:'N'})
>>> result
  India UK US    Skills
0     Y  N  N   Finance
1     N  Y  N       Law
2     N  N  Y  Computer
```

One line

```py
pd.concat([dummies, df], axis=1).drop('Country', axis=1).replace({1:'Y', 0:'N'})
  India UK US    Skills
0     Y  N  N   Finance
1     N  Y  N       Law
2     N  N  Y  Computer
```

Comment: df = pd.concat([pd.get_dummies(df['Country']),df['Skills']],axis=1).replace({1:'Y', 0:'N'})

Answer (score 0):

Try -

```
df = pd.concat([pd.get_dummies(df['Country']),df['Skills']],axis=1).replace({1:'Y', 0:'N'})
```